# error while showing Toast in AsyncTask Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, toast

In my RSS reader app, I'm trying to check whether the input RSS url is valid. If so, I will save it in SQLite database. My approach is to use AsyncTask:

```
class mAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
{
    private boolean succeed = false;

    public mAsyncTask()
    {
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls)
    {
        try
        {
            URL sourceUrl = new URL(sourceUrlString);

            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

            // We will get the XML from an input stream
            xpp.setInput(global.getInputStream(sourceUrl), "UTF_8");

            // if it reach here, it means the XML is in a valid
            // format
            if (xpp.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
            {
                if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
                    sourceTitle = xpp.nextText();
                succeed = true;
            }
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Input RSS feed is not in the valid format...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch (XmlPullParserException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unknown error occurred..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return "Complete doInBackground";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress)
    {
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (succeed == true)
        {
            db.addSource(new Sources("", sourceTitle, sourceUrlString));

                            //refresh
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

`sourceUrlString` is the input String from AlertDialog. `db` is the database handler class. `Sources` constructor held 3 variables: category, title, and url of a feed, all of which are String.

Based on LogCat, I get an error everytime it tries to show the Toast inside `catchs`. Any idea why?

Also, this is my first attempt in implementing AsyncTask, so should you notice any inefficient code, please let me know.

Comment: cannot show toast in `doInbackground` because you cannot update ui from a background thread and doInbackground is invoked on the background thread

Comment: You can't shoe Toast in doInBackground

Comment: use System.out.println() because u cant update ui in asynctask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since doInBackGround run on seperate thread , you cannot show toast from there mean updating UI. But you can update UI from onPreExecute, onPostExecute and onProgressUpdate beacuse they run on the main thread. Therefore , you can use these method to update UI.

So you can publishProgress to call onProgressUpdate to show toast or simply return some value to onPostexecute and on the basis of that show toast..

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

You cannot show `Toast` in `doInbackground`. So try like below.

In `doInBackground` return string like below.

```
protected String doInBackground(String... urls)
{
    try
    {
        URL sourceUrl = new URL(sourceUrlString);

        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

        // We will get the XML from an input stream
        xpp.setInput(global.getInputStream(sourceUrl), "UTF_8");

        // if it reach here, it means the XML is in a valid
        // format
        if (xpp.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
        {
            if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
                sourceTitle = xpp.nextText();
            succeed = true;
        }
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        return "MalformedURLException";
        e.printStackTrace();        }
    catch (XmlPullParserException e)
    {
        return "XmlPullParserException";
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        return "IOException";
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return "Exception";            
    }

    return "Complete doInBackground";
}
```

In `onPostExecute` check like below and show `Toast`

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
{
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    if(result.equals("Exception"))
    {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unknown error occurred..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else if(result.equals("IOException"))
    {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "IOException..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else if(result.equals("XmlPullParserException"))
    {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "XmlPullParserException..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else if(result.equals("MalformedURLException"))
    {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MalformedURLException..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{


    if(succeed)
    {
        db.addSource(new Sources("", sourceTitle, sourceUrlString));

                        //refresh
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

UI always runs in separate thread and you cant change UI from other thread.Use Handler for updating UI from background thread.

```
               handler = new Handler();
                handler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override

                public void run() {

                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unknown error occurred..",       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
         });
```

Comment: lol you posted even the lines number. Wanted to edit it, but being a lazy ninja, I felt lazy to delete the lines number.

Answer (score 1):

`doInBackground()` methods runs in in its separate Thread. It doesnt allow to interact with `UIThread`. You want to display a Toast Message that actually is function of UIThread to handle.

As long as your control is in worker thread, you can not update your UI. For AsyncTask class `onPreExecute()` & `onProgressUpdate()` only these two methods allows to interact with UI as they gets execute on UIThread.

Answer (score 0):

You should call Toast on a UI Thread.

Answer (score 0):

Toast should be called on a UI Thread. If you want show toast in doBackground() you can achieve it by using `runOnUiThread`();

```
catch (Exception e)
{
        YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unknown error occurred..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement this through `runOnUiThread()`. `Asynctask` runs in separate thread so you can not update UI from `doInBackground()`.

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unknown error occurred..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
});
```